# how to load Image and use it in canvas with gatsby SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, gatsby

The problem is I could not create image with none of the supported types : `CSSImageValue` or `HTMLImageElement` or `SVGImageElement` or `HTMLVideoElement` or `HTMLCanvasElement` or `ImageBitmap` or `OffscreenCanvas` in my SSR application with gatsby .

I tried `canvas` npm package `Canvas.Image` to make image HTMLImageElement 
 but it has same error with Image constructor message too.

my main error message :

```sh
Context.js:225 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
```

node `canvas` package code and error message :

```
import { Image as CanvasImage } from 'canvas';

const image = new CanvasImage();
image.src = avatars[avatar];

console.log(image);
```

```sh
TypeError: canvas__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Image is not a constructor
```

I use `react-konva` package to draw canvas and `Image` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the way to do this.
I create a function named `getImage` which gonna load image source from `canvas` `loadImage` method with a `Promise` :

```js
import { loadImage } from 'canvas';

export async function getImage(src, cb) {
  return loadImage(src)
    .then((image) => image)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

And use it in my component with ease :

```js
let [imageSource, setImageSource] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
  getImage(ladderSvg)
    .then((image) => setImageSource(image))
} , []);
```